# Django Cookiecutter how do i change the production media storage to local

Tags: django, docker, local-storage, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

i have a issue with the django Cookiecutter on a docker production, my problem is that the default configuration uses Amazon s3 to manage the static files and the media files, but what i want is to store these files locally on my docker.... i dont know how to do that!

Thank you in advance

Comment: cookiecutter-django is currently using caddy but I think they consider to switch back to nginx. Which web server are you using?